# Get JSON data from PHP function using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send data coming from a php function to my HTML page using AJAX, my function look like:

```
     function getFeed() {
        $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = simplexml_load_string($content);
        $articles= array();

        foreach( $data->channel->item as $item){

            $articles[]=array(
                'title'         =>  (string)$item->title,
                'description'   =>  (string)$item->description,
                'link'          =>  (string)$item->link,
                'Date'          =>  (string)$item->pubDate,
            );
        }

        foreach($articles as $article){
        echo json_encode($article['title']);
        }
    }
```

my javascript script look like:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php',
        success: function (data){
        console.log('success',data);
        }
    });
});
```

Once I execute the code, I get a '`success'` message in the console, but not the data. 
So, how can I get the JSON data in this case?

Comment: are you sure that you are calling `getFeed` after defining it ?

Comment: There's no need to encode every item. Just `json_encode($articles)`

Comment: @HassanAhmed I don't call it, how should I do in my javascript script

Comment: if you call "/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php" in your browser, do you get the desired results ?

Comment: you can't , you have to call it from your -server side- , in another words from your php file

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you. I've tried that but still no response, in the Network element inspeting, I get this message (This request has o response data availble )

Comment: @HassanAhmed how can I do that ?

Comment: When you're making an ajax call (that's from the browser side) the url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php' should be available from the browser

Comment: What's the code of `/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php`?

Comment: @u_mulder it contain just this function, I mean getFeed()

Comment: Do you call this function? Do you know how to call functions in php?

Comment: In other words,  do you ever call `getFeed()` in that file

Comment: @u_mulder where I call it ? some people says that you don't have to hybridate two languages !

Comment: In your php-file is there a line: `getFeed()`?

Comment: @u_mulder No, it contain just what I publish here

Comment: append `getFeed();` to the last of your rssnews.inc.php file

Comment: Then add this line. And read a manual on php site http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php.

Comment: add javascript code dataType: "json"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change script like this

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?function=getFeed',
        success: function (data){
        console.log('success',data);
        }
    });
});
```

in your "rssnews.inc.php" file write this code

```
if(isset($_GET['function']) && $_GET['function'] !=''){
    $result = $_GET['function']();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
function getFeed() {
    $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = simplexml_load_string($content);
    $articles= array();

    foreach( $data->channel->item as $item){

        $articles[]=array(
            'title'         =>  (string)$item->title,
            'description'   =>  (string)$item->description,
            'link'          =>  (string)$item->link,
            'Date'          =>  (string)$item->pubDate,
        );
    }

    $articalesArr = array();
    foreach($articles as $article){
        array_push($articalesArr, $article['title']);    
    }
    return $articalesArr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to know just how to call the function and where ?

Comment: Thank you so much this is really work, if you can, just explain to me what's happen

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the all of JSON data from your method [getFeed], You can return the value instead of echoing it.

```
 function getFeed() {
    $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = simplexml_load_string($content);
    $articles= array();

    foreach($data->channel->item as $item) {

        $articles[]=array(
            'title'         =>  (string)$item->title,
            'description'   =>  (string)$item->description,
            'link'          =>  (string)$item->link,
            'Date'          =>  (string)$item->pubDate,
        );
    }

    return json_encode($articles);
}
```

Then in your JS, You can use the $.parseJSON to see the results.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php',
    success: function (data) {
        var oJsonResponse = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(oJsonResponse);
    }
});
```

You would get the results like this:

[image]

Hope this helps for you

Comment: Thank you. I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.success (test.php:33)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Have you try to console the {data} first? And make sure you've return all of the data using "return json_encode($articles);" from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> Your javascript function should be as below

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php',
        success: function (data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                console.log(data[i].title);
             }
        }
    });
});
```